# Converting UTF characters but only if

Tags: php, character, utf

Ok, so i've found a font on typekit i really really like and suits the design very well.

Unfortunately this font lacks the character **"Č"** but has **"Ž,Š"**. What i am trying to do is that if there is a **Č** in the title, i want the **Č** to be converted to a **C** that the font can normally display. So **Č->C**.

This is the code i've put together now, but now it converts all the characters.

```
<?php 
$title_converted = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $title);
echo '<h1 id="intro-title" ' . $team_name_class_full . '>' . iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $title_converted) . '</h1>';
```

Could you help me out futher please.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use plain old [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to do this.

```
$title_converted = str_replace("Č", "C", $title);
```

Comment: Doesnt'seem to work. 

First step (convert)

<?php $title_converted = str_replace("Č", "C", $title); ?>

Second step (Output)

echo '<h1 id="intro-title" ' . $team_name_class_full . '>' . $title_converted . '</h1>';

Comment: @Svedr In case it's a lowercase letter you'd have to replace that separately - if that's your issue. Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean.